# Python ValueError when multiplying integers

Tags: python

I searched for this error, but I didn't find answer. Simple calc program:

```
import sys
from sys import argv

first = int(sys.argv[1]) 
operation = sys.argv[2]
second = int(sys.argv[3])

if operation == '+':
    total = first + second        
if operation == '-':
    total = first - second
if operation == '*':
    total = first * second
if operation == '/':
    total = first / second

print "%d %s %d = %d" % (first, operation, second, total)
```

When I enter: `python first.py 2 / 2` I get correct output, same with `-` and `+`, but when I enter `python first.py 2 * 2` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 7, in <module>
    second = int(sys.argv[3])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'first.py'`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is a *shell meta character*, meaning: list all the files in the current directory here.

As a result, `sys.argv` does not get set to `['first.py', '2', '*', '2']` but to `['first.py', '2', 'some-filename.txt', 'first.py', 'another-filename.py', '2']` or similar, because the shell has expanded `*` to all filenames first, *then* called Python with those names.

Escape the `*` in the shell:

```sh
python first.py 2 \* 2
```